# MODIS emissivity extraction using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, remote-sensing, satellite, modis-reprojection-tool

I  am doing validation of 40 Landsat images.now I need two spectral emissivities of the 8-day MODIS land surface temperature and emissivity product (MOD11A2).and I have to extract emissivities for MODIS band 31 and 32 for each imaging date.

How do I do it with ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS doesn't handle HDF files very well, so you might need to use some other methods to extract the data. You could use the MODIS Reprojection Tool, or if you have access to ENVI/IDL, you can use them to read and export the data.

Comment: I have access to ENVI.could you please mention some basic steps to retrieve emissivity from MODIS?